# Display Specific Fields (Through Parse) from JSON response in Python

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I am looking to display specific fields from a JSON Response returned from the following URL in a printed list in the cli:

http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=5&vendor_id=26&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=1&opec=1&opov=1&opcsrf=1&opfileinc=1&opgpriv=0&opsqli=1&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=2&cvssscoremin=0

I am able to output the JSON response using requests library as such:

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=5&vendor_id=26&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=1&opec=1&opov=1&opcsrf=1&opfileinc=1&opgpriv=0&opsqli=1&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=2&cvssscoremin=0"
response = urllib.urlopen();
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```

However I am unsure of where to put my variables to tell the print data command which specific fields to display.

The JSON response is formed as such and each value is preceeded by a 'u' tag:

```
{u'update_date': u'2014-11-18', u'cve_id': u'CVE-2014-4114', u'exploit_count': u'3', u'summary': u'Microsoft Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 SP2 and R2 SP1, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 Gold and R2, and Windows RT Gold and 8.1 allow remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted OLE object in an Office document, as exploited in the wild with a &quot;Sandworm&quot; attack in June through October 2014, aka &quot;Windows OLE Remote Code Execution Vulnerability.&quot;', u'url': u'http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-4114/', u'publish_date': u'2014-10-15', u'cvss_score': u'9.3', u'cwe_id': u'20'}`
```

I am looking to have a list view as such:

```
update_date:
cve_id:
exploit_count:
```

etc...

Comment: Actually, that URL returns a *list* with dictionaries. You are missing the `[...]` brackets from the real response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `u'...'` syntax means you have Unicode strings. They are a lot like the regular `'...'` strings; when the contents are just ASCII text there is no difference. You have a *list* of dictionaries here, so index to each individual dictionary then just use strings as keys:

```
print data[0]['update_date']
```

to print that specific value, or loop over all of the dictionary items:

```
for index, entry in enumerate(data, 1):
    print 'Item {}'.format(index)
    for name, value in entry.items():
        print '    {}: {}'.format(name, value)
```

where I used a `str.format()` template to print each item with a colon after the key name, as well as use `enumerate()` to give each item a number.

Demo with the data from the URL you gave:

```
>>> for index, entry in enumerate(data, 1):
...     print 'Item {}'.format(index)
...     for name, value in entry.items():
...         print '    {}: {}'.format(name, value)
... 
Item 1
    update_date: 2014-11-18
    cve_id: CVE-2014-4114
    exploit_count: 3
    summary: Microsoft Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 SP2 and R2 SP1, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 Gold and R2, and Windows RT Gold and 8.1 allow remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted OLE object in an Office document, as exploited in the wild with a &quot;Sandworm&quot; attack in June through October 2014, aka &quot;Windows OLE Remote Code Execution Vulnerability.&quot;
    url: http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-4114/
    publish_date: 2014-10-15
    cvss_score: 9.3
    cwe_id: 20
Item 2
    update_date: 2014-05-16
    cve_id: CVE-2014-0322
    exploit_count: 2
    summary: Use-after-free vulnerability in Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 and 10 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via vectors involving crafted JavaScript code, CMarkup, and the onpropertychange attribute of a script element, as exploited in the wild in January and February 2014.
    url: http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-0322/
    publish_date: 2014-02-14
    cvss_score: 9.3
    cwe_id: 399
Item 3
    update_date: 2014-04-14
    cve_id: CVE-2014-2671
    exploit_count: 1
    summary: Microsoft Windows Media Player (WMP) 11.0.5721.5230 allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (memory corruption) or possibly have unspecified other impact via a crafted WAV file.
    url: http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-2671/
    publish_date: 2014-03-31
    cvss_score: 6.8
    cwe_id: 119
Item 4
    update_date: 2014-03-26
    cve_id: CVE-2014-0307
    exploit_count: 1
    summary: Use-after-free vulnerability in Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service (memory corruption) via a certain sequence of manipulations of a TextRange element, aka &quot;Internet Explorer Memory Corruption Vulnerability.&quot;
    url: http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-0307/
    publish_date: 2014-03-12
    cvss_score: 9.3
    cwe_id: 119
Item 5
    update_date: 2014-01-17
    cve_id: CVE-2013-3906
    exploit_count: 1
    summary: GDI+ in Microsoft Windows Vista SP2 and Server 2008 SP2; Office 2003 SP3, 2007 SP3, and 2010 SP1 and SP2; Office Compatibility Pack SP3; and Lync 2010, 2010 Attendee, 2013, and Basic 2013 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted TIFF image, as demonstrated by an image in a Word document, and exploited in the wild in October and November 2013.
    url: http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-3906/
    publish_date: 2013-11-06
    cvss_score: 9.3
    cwe_id: 94
```

Note that the code, as posted, won't run as you did not actually pass your URL to the `urllib.urlopen()` function:

```
url = "http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=5&vendor_id=26&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=1&opec=1&opov=1&opcsrf=1&opfileinc=1&opgpriv=0&opsqli=1&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=2&cvssscoremin=0"
response = urllib.urlopen();
```

The semi-colon is not needed either; pass in the `url` argument instead:

```
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. It throws the following error when I try and print the 2 part output:

`response = urllib.urlopen();
TypeError: urlopen() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

`import urllib, json
url = "JSONREQUESTURL"
response = urllib.urlopen();
data = json.loads(response.read())
for name, value in data.items():
    print '{}: {}'.format(name, value)`

Do I need urlllib2 for this to work?

Comment: @cam_i_rooni: you did not pass the URL to `url.urlopen()`... Did you even try to use the code?

Comment: Yes I am passing the full URL just did not include in the commented code because of char limit. Yes I did the above and it works but only prints the last JSON response of the 5 returned. I assume this is to do the amount of prints and I will try and solve. Thanks for all your Help Martijn!